# Swift 4 Error serializing json typeMismatch

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to parse data from a static JSON file to my entitys but I'm getting following error: `Error serializing json typeMismatch`

The idea is to create a formula collection app. The collection of formulas should be loaded every time the app gets started by loading a JSON. This way it is easier to update the formula list.

I guess the JSON explains the intended data structure.

My JSON:

```
[
    {
        "category_name": "Wasserbau",
        "icon": "wave",
        "formula_list": [
            {
                "formula_name": "Formel 1",
                "formula_description": "Demo Formel fÃ¼r Testat",
                "formula": "x=y/z",
                "favorite": false
            },
            {
                "formula_name": "Formel 2",
                "formula_description": "Demo Formel fÃ¼r Testat",
                "formula": "x=y/z",
                "favorite": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "Strassenbau",
        "icon": "wave",
        "formula_list": [
            {
                "formula_name": "Formel 3",
                "formula_description": "Demo Formel fÃ¼r Testat",
                "formula": "x=y/z",
                "favorite": false
            },
            {
                "formula_name": "Formel 4",
                "formula_description": "Demo Formel fÃ¼r Testat",
                "formula": "x=y/z",
                "favorite": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category_name": "Hochbau",
        "icon": "wave",
        "formula_list": [
            {
                "formula_name": "Formel 5",
                "formula_description": "Demo Formel fÃ¼r Testat",
                "formula": "x=y/z",
                "favorite": false
            },
            {
                "formula_name": "Formel 6",
                "formula_description": "Demo Formel fÃ¼r Testat",
                "formula": "x=y/z",
                "favorite": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The function where I try to parse the JSON:

```
 func loadCategoryJSONData() {
        let jsonUrlString = "https://joshuahemmings.ch/data.json"

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {return} //
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            print("JSON Response: ")
            print(data)
            do {
                let categoryJSONData =  try JSONDecoder().decode(CategoryList.self, from: data)
                for category in categoryJSONData.data {
                    print(category.categoryName)
                }
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json", jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
```

And my Entitys:

```
struct CategoryList: Decodable {
        let data: [Category]
    }

    struct Formula: Codable {
        let formulaName : String
        let formulaDescription : String
        let formula : String
        let favorite: Bool

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case formulaName = "formula_name"
            case formulaDescription = "formula_description"
            case formula
            case favorite
        }
        init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
            self.formulaName = dictionary["formulaName"] as? String ?? ""
            self.formulaDescription = dictionary["formulaDescription"] as? String ?? ""
            self.formula = dictionary["formula"] as? String ?? ""
            self.favorite = dictionary["favorite"] as? Bool ?? false
        }
    }

    struct Category: Codable {
        let categoryName: String
        let icon: String
        let formulaList: [Formula]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case categoryName = "category_name"
            case icon = "icon"
            case formulaList = "formula_list"
        }

        init(_ dictionary: [String: Any]) {
            self.categoryName = dictionary["categoryName"] as? String ?? ""
            self.icon = dictionary["icon"] as? String ?? ""
            self.formulaList = dictionary["formulaList"] as? [Formula] ?? []
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wha'ts the full error message? Your JSON is an array at top level, you don't have a "data" key in it. So instead of `decode(CategoryList.self`, try `decode([Category].self` instead at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is in declaring type to parse this `JSON`.

You're not having `CategoryList` here, it would be something like:

```
{
    "data": [ … <Category JSON> … ]
}
```

You're having just `[Category]` here, like JSON root is `Array`(`[]`), not `Object`(`{}`).

So instead of

```
try decoder.decode(CategoryList.self, from: data)
```

You should do

```
try decoder.decode([Category].self, from: data)
```

---

Also, if your coding keys are almost the same as keys in JSON, but not in snake case, you should not declare custom `CodingKey` for your type. Use proper [.keyDecodingStrategy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase) instead.

```
struct Formula: Codable {
    let formulaName: String
    let formulaDescription: String
    let formula: String
    let favorite: Bool
}

struct Category: Codable {
    let categoryName: String
    let icon: String
    let formulaList: [Formula]
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let categoryJSONData =  try decoder.decode([Category].self, from: data)
```